# How to accumulate state across tests in py.test

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I currently have a project and tests similar to these.

```
class mylib:
    @classmethod
    def get_a(cls):
        return 'a'

    @classmethod
    def convert_a_to_b(cls, a):
        return 'b'

    @classmethod
    def works_with(cls, a, b):
        return True

class TestMyStuff(object):
    def test_first(self):
        self.a = mylib.get_a()

    def test_conversion(self):
        self.b = mylib.convert_a_to_b(self.a)

    def test_a_works_with_b(self):
        assert mylib.works_with(self.a, self.b)
```

With py.test 0.9.2, these tests (or similar ones) pass. With later versions of py.test, test_conversion and test_a_works_with_b fail with 'TestMyStuff has no attribute a'.

I am guessing this is because with later builds of py.test, a separate instance of TestMyStuff is created for each method that is tested.

What is the proper way to write these tests such that results can be given for each of the steps in the sequence, but the state from a previous (successful) test can (must) be used to perform subsequent tests?

Comment: Useful pytest docs section on incremental testing: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/simple.html#incremental-testing-test-steps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good unit test practice is to avoid state accumulated across tests.  Most unit test frameworks go to great lengths to prevent you from accumulating state.  The reason is that you want each test to stand on its own.  This lets you run arbitrary subsets of your tests, and ensures that your system is in a clean state for each test.

Comment: So in this case, would you have test_a_works_with_b call test_conversion and it call test_first, so that the necessary accumulated state has occurred... or just repeat one's self in those tests that require the state to be present?

Comment: My preference would be to put common code in helper methods and then call the helpers as needed from each test.  Calling a test method from another test method would work but seems funny to me.

Comment: I disagree with this. pytest fixtures were made for this reason and avoid unnecessary/unwanted setup/teardown. I would amend this by saying that you don't want to accumulate state *unintentionally*. I have made a separate answer with a  solution to this....

Comment: One use case: gathering metrics during test execution so you can plot something at the end with pyplot. The metrics are unrelated to whether the tests pass or fail, but they're still a useful artefact.

Answer (score 10):

I partly agree with Ned in that it's good to avoid somewhat random sharing of test state. But i also think it is sometimes useful to accumulate state incrementally during tests.

With py.test you can actually do that by making it explicit that you want to share test state.  Your example rewritten to work:

```
class State:
    """ holding (incremental) test state """

def pytest_funcarg__state(request):
    return request.cached_setup(
        setup=lambda: State(),
        scope="module"
    )

class mylib:
    @classmethod
    def get_a(cls):
        return 'a'

    @classmethod
    def convert_a_to_b(cls, a):
        return 'b'

    @classmethod
    def works_with(cls, a, b):
        return True

class TestMyStuff(object):
    def test_first(self, state):
        state.a = mylib.get_a()

    def test_conversion(self, state):
        state.b = mylib.convert_a_to_b(state.a)

    def test_a_works_with_b(self, state):
        mylib.works_with(state.a, state.b)
```

You can run this with recent py.test versions.  Each functions receives a "state" object and the "funcarg" factory creates it initially and caches it over the module scope. Together with the py.test guarantee that tests are run in file order the test functions can be rather they will work incrementally on the test "state".

However, It is a bit fragile because if you select just the running of "test_conversion" via e.g. "py.test -k test_conversion" then your test will fail because the first test hasn't run. I think that some way to do incremental tests would be nice so maybe we can eventually find a totally robust solution.

HTH,
holger

Comment: Thanks. That does help. That's also particularly useful when you want to share state across modules, classes in a module, or just test methods within a class, and be explicit about the boundary.

Comment: Stumbled upon this while trying to implement the "incremental" pattern from pytest's doc (https://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html#incremental-testing-test-steps). The state trick looks cool, although a bit cumbersome; wouldn't it be better to just add a special decorator that tells pytest that a class should only be instanciated once?

Answer (score 8):

This is surely a job for pytest fixtures: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html

> Fixtures allow test functions to easily receive and work against specific pre-initialized application objects without having to care about import/setup/cleanup details. It’s a prime example of dependency injection where fixture functions take the role of the injector and test functions are the consumers of fixture objects.

So an example of setting up a fixture to hold state would be as follows:

```
import pytest


class State:

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = {}


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def state() -> State:
    state = State()
    state.state['from_fixture'] = 0
    return state


def test_1(state: State) -> None:
    state.state['from_test_1'] = 1
    assert state.state['from_fixture'] == 0
    assert state.state['from_test_1'] == 1


def test_2(state: State) -> None:
    state.state['from_test_2'] = 2
    assert state.state['from_fixture'] == 0
    assert state.state['from_test_1'] == 1
    assert state.state['from_test_2'] == 2
```

Note that you can specify the scope for the dependency injection (and hence the state). In this case I have set it to session, the other option would be `module` (`scope=function` wouldn't work for your use-case as you would lose state between functions.

Obviously you can extend this pattern to hold other types of objects in the state, such as comparing outcomes from different tests.

As a word of warning - you still want to be able to run your tests in any order (my example breaches this s swapping the order of 1 and 2 results in failure). However I have not illustrated that for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Nice. This approach has the benefit of allowing the scope of the state to be declared, explicit, and readily specified. Since my OP, I've come to use fixtures extensively, as their design almost always provides exactly the right function.

Comment: OK cool, no worries. Maybe make this the accepted answer? I think the current one is a bit misleading.

Comment: And yes, fixtures are very helpful :), especially as your tests start to grow in number.  You can even build on other fixtures using composition if you need to specialise them.

Comment: I still think Ned's answer is the best. Engineering tests to run independently is more important than finding elegant ways to make tests interdependent. Ned's advice led me to realize that the pattern I'd inherited was a bad one in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [hpk42's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3253965/7262247), you can also use [pytest-steps](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-steps/) to perform incremental testing, this can help you in particular if you wish to share some kind of incremental state/intermediate results between the steps.

With this package you do not need to put all the steps in a class (you can, but it is not required), simply decorate your "test suite" function with `@test_steps`.

EDIT: there is a new 'generator' mode to make it even easier:

```
from pytest_steps import test_steps

@test_steps('step_first', 'step_conversion', 'step_a_works_with_b')
def test_suite_with_shared_results():
    a = mylib.get_a()
    yield

    b = mylib.convert_a_to_b(a)
    yield

    assert mylib.works_with(a, b)
    yield
```

LEGACY answer:

You can add a `steps_data` parameter to your test function if you wish to share a `StepsDataHolder` object between your steps.

Your example would then write:

```
from pytest_steps import test_steps, StepsDataHolder

def step_first(steps_data):
    steps_data.a = mylib.get_a()


def step_conversion(steps_data):
    steps_data.b = mylib.convert_a_to_b(steps_data.a)


def step_a_works_with_b(steps_data):
    assert mylib.works_with(steps_data.a, steps_data.b)


@test_steps(step_first, step_conversion, step_a_works_with_b)
def test_suite_with_shared_results(test_step, steps_data: StepsDataHolder):

    # Execute the step with access to the steps_data holder
    test_step(steps_data)
```

Finally, note that you can automatically skip or fail a step if another has failed using `@depends_on`, check in the [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-steps/) for details.

(I'm the author of this package by the way ;) )

Answer (score 1):

As I spent more time with this problem, I realized there was an implicit aspect to my question that I neglected to specify. In most scenarios, I found that I wanted to accumulate state within a single class, but discard it when the test class had completed.

What I ended up using for some of my classes, where the class itself represented a process that accumulated state, I stored the accumulated state in the class object itself.

```
class mylib:
    @classmethod
    def get_a(cls):
        return 'a'

    @classmethod
    def convert_a_to_b(cls, a):
        return 'b'

    @classmethod
    def works_with(cls, a, b):
        return True

class TestMyStuff(object):
    def test_first(self):
        self.__class__.a = mylib.get_a()

    def test_conversion(self):
        self.__class__.b = mylib.convert_a_to_b(self.a)

    def test_a_works_with_b(self):
        mylib.works_with(self.a, self.b)
```

The advantage to this approach is it keeps the state encapsulated within the test class (there are no auxiliary functions that have to be present for the test to run), and it would be suitably awkward for a different class to expect the TestMyStuff state to be present when the different class runs.

I think each of these approaches discussed thusfar have their merits, and intend to use each approach where it fits best.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess the example i provided above actually work with cached_setup(..., scope="class"). Currently only module/session/function scopes are supported but it's easy to extend towards classes, the need arose also in other contexts.  Happy about an issue so i don't forget to go for it :)