# Pytest: Runtime parametrization of a test

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pytest

Does anyone know of a workaround to dynamically parametrize a pytest test.

Example:

```
resp = []

def test_1():
    r = requests.get(<some url>)
    resp = <parse a list out of response r>


@pytest.mark.parameterize("response",resp)
def test_2(response):
    <Use resp values and pass it one by one to another api>
```

I came across the following issue on pytest github which is almost same as my issue.

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3273

As per this discussion, pytest parametrizes test before execution of any test. Runtime parametrization is not supported. Does anyone know of a workaround or a pythonic way to handle this behavior?

Comment: Changing the test set after the test execution has started is a dangerous path to enter and isn't supported in `pytest` for a reason. Why do you need it anyway? Extract the `resp` filling code to a separate function and call it before the test execution starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrian Krupa's answer is close, now add response parametrization:

```
CANNED_RESPONSES = dict(OK=200, REDIRECT=304, SERVER_ERROR=500)
RESPONSE = 'response'

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if RESPONSE in metafunc.fixturenames:
        ids = list(CANNED_RESPONSES.keys())
        responses = list(CANNED_RESPONSES.values())
        metafunc.parametrize(RESPONSE, responses, ids=ids)


def test_flar(response):
    print response
```

This way you can get named ids in -v and multiple tests for a set of canned answers:

```
test_in.py::test_flar[OK] 200
PASSED
test_in.py::test_flar[REDIRECT] 304
PASSED
test_in.py::test_flar[SERVER_ERROR] 500
PASSED
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make the tests to depend on each other. It's not a good practice as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145756/1351828).

If you want to reuse request response you can wrap it into a [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html).

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def response():
    import requests
    return requests.get(<some url>)

def test(response):
    <Use resp values and pass it one by one to another api>
```

It would be also a good idea to mock the request to make tests independent from a remote resource. You can use [responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) library for that.

```
import responses
import requests

@responses.activate
def test_simple():
    responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://twitter.com/api/1/foobar',
                  json={'error': 'not found'}, status=404)

    resp = requests.get('http://twitter.com/api/1/foobar')
```

Comment: but this way I won't be able to achieve parameterization in the test. It would be nice to parse the value of response and run test for every value. Is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: Then parametrize the tests with request params, make request in test and use response. It will be easier to maintain. But you should avoid making true requests in your tests (if they are not integration tests.